# Why is the biconditional true if both components are false?

Tags: logic

I already know that [a false statement implies anything](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53781/53259). Because I ask only for intuition, please do not answer with formal proofs or use truth tables (which I already understand).

Source: p 333, *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (12 Ed, 2014), by Patrick J. Hurley

> The truth table shows that the biconditional is true when its two components have the
>   same truth value and that otherwise it is false. These results are required by the fact
>   that p ≡ q is simply a shorter way of writing (p ⊃ q) ∧ (q ⊃ p). If p and q are either both
>   true or both false, then p ⊃ q and q ⊃ p are both true, making their conjunction true. [...]

I understand the above by rewriting p ≡ q as (p ⊃ q) ∧ (q ⊃ p); but without relying on this expansion, how can you intuit this directly?

`Epilogue:` With the aid below, I finally comprehended my problem as summarised [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31004/why-is-the-biconditional-true-if-both-components-are-false#comment73231_31005). I had confused 'True' with 'Truth Value'. To wit, the Truth of ≡ is decided by the similarity or difference of the two Truth Values on either side of ≡, and is NOT decided by the truth values.
So even if both p and q are false, p and q have the same Truth Value (because they are both false), and so are logically equivalent.

Comment: Well, it's not true that "a false statement implies anything"—just that a material conditional with a false antecedent can be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition is:

1. The biconditional X ≡ Y says "X and Y always have the same truth value."
2. Therefore either X and Y are both true; or X and Y are both false.
3. Another name for the biconditional is is equivalence, or logical equivalence. That name carries more of the intuition. X and Y are equivalent. Either both are true or both are false.
4. If they're both true, each implies the other because True implies True.
5. If they're both false, each implies the other because False implies False.

You can run these points from top to bottom or bottom to top to suit your intuition and whatever presentation is in the book.

Comment: Thanks. I hope that you do not mind my addition of numbering. Can you please clarify 5? I do not understand: `each implies the other because False implies False`.

Comment: @LePressentiment False implies False. You already mentioned that in your question so I took that as given. If X and Y are both false, then X implies Y and Y implies X because False implies False.

Comment: @LePressentiment - you started your question with "I already know that a false statement implies anything"; thus "a false statement implies anything false".

Comment: @user4894 Thank you. I now understand 5, but how does 5 (ie: 2 false propositions) imply that the (material) biconditional is true? I still find strange deriving truth from 2 false propositions?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you. Now I understand 5.

Comment: @LePressentiment If X and Y are both false, they both have the same truth value. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question. Saying X and Y are equivalent means they have the same truth value. So either they're both true or they're both false.

Comment: Thank you. I think that you perceived the underlying confusion; the truth of 'equivalence' is decided by the similarity or difference of the two truth values are the same, and NOT on the truth values themselves? So even if p and q are false, they have the same truth value (because they are both false), and so they are equivalent? Is this correct?

Comment: @LePressentiment Yes exactly.

Comment: Thank you. Wish you to update your answer by rephrasing my comment more eloquently, which will aid others?

Comment: This is not a good answer. It is confusing the material biconditional with logical equivalence. The definition quoted from Hurley's textbook clearly equates the material biconditional p ≡ q with the conjunction of p ⊃ q and q ⊃ p. The material biconditional merely states that p and q have the same truth value.

Comment: @Bumble My 2015 self is appropriately humbled. I'm not familiar with this particular text. I'm afraid I don't see a big distinction between logical equivalence and biconditional. You say "The material biconditional merely states that p and q have the same truth value." Isn't that the same as saying that they are logically equivalent? Perhaps I'm missing a subtlety. If I need to prove two propositions are logically equivalent I'll show that they imply each other or that they always have the same truth value under all variable assignments. Is that wrong?

Comment: A material biconditional does not say anything about variable assignments. It merely says of two propositions that they have the same truth value. The material biconditional: "Canada is a country ≡ Mercury is a planet" is true, as is "Canada is a piece of cheese ≡ Donald Trump is a planet". But there is no logical connection in either case. φ and ψ are logically equivalent if the material biconditional is a logical truth. A material biconditional is "φ ≡ ψ" and logical equivalence is "⊨ φ ≡ ψ". Unlike Hurley, I prefer to use ↔ since some authors use ≡ for other things.

Comment: @Bumble You seem to be right. I found https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649394/difference-between-biconditional-and-logical-equivalence and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649394/difference-between-biconditional-and-logical-equivalence.

Answer (score 3):

In the simplified semantics for logical languages, *meaning* is "proxied" by the *truth conditions* for sentences.

There is a long tradition in modern logic regarding "extensionality". From Frege's [Begriffsschrift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffsschrift) onwards, mathematical logic has been concerned mainly with truth-functional contexts.

According to Frege, the *reference* ([Bedeutung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_and_reference)) of a proposition is its truth-value, either the **True** or the **False**. For Frege, complete propositions, like names, have objects as their *Bedeutungen*, and in particular, the truth-values the **True** or the **False**. In this way, he is able to transcribe sentential connectives such as “and” and “or,” etc., as truth functions in the strictest sense — functions that take truth-values as argument and yield truth-values as value.

According to Alfred North Whitehead & Bertrand Russell, [Principia Mathematica to *56](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&pg=PA115) (2nd ed - 1927), page 115 :

> It is obvious that two propositions are equivalent when, and only when, both are true or both are false. Following Frege, we shall call the truthvalue of a proposition truth if it is true, and falsehood if it is false. Thus two propositions are equivalent when they have the same truth-value.
>
> We shall give the name of a truth-function to a function **f(p)** whose argument is a proposition, and whose truth-value depends only upon the truth-value of its argument. All the functions of propositions with which we shall be specially concerned will be truth-functions, i.e. we shall have
>
> > **p≡q.⊃.f(p)≡f(q)**.
>
> The reason of this is, that the functions of propositions with which we deal are all built up by means of the primitive ideas. But it is not a universal characteristic of functions of propositions to be truth-functions. For example, "A believes **p**" may be true for one true value of **p** and false for another.

In "modern" terms, this is the so-called *Replacement theorem*; see S.C.Kleene, [Introduction to Metamathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=HZAjPwAACAAJ) (1952), page 116 :

> If **A** and **B** are formulas, **C_A** is a formula constructed from a specified occurnce of **A** using only the [truth-functional connectives], and **C_B** results from **C_A** by replacing this occurrence of **A** by **B**, then **A ↔ B ⊢ C_A ↔ C_B**.

In a "universe" of *extensional* contexts, like that considered by the simplified semantics of logical languages, it is natural to equate the condition for two equivalent formulae having the same *truth conditions* with that of expressing "the same thing", i.e. "having the same *meaning*".

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am quite confused because it appears too complicated for me; I am only starting logic. Can you simplify it please?